# glmer from R package lme4 asking to scale variables even though variables already scaled

Tags: r, scaling, glm, lme4

I have a dataset with 27 variables and ~30,000 observations. The first 17 variables are continuous and the remainder are binary. When running glmer with the model specified as all the fixed effects + random effect intercept based on a subject ID, I keep getting a warning message that:

```
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl=control$checkConv, :
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
- Rescale variables?
```

All the continuous variables were scaled using the "scale" function with center and scale set to TRUE. So I don't understand why I keep getting this message. Some of the variables are a little bit skewed, could that be leading to the warning?

Comment: Can you post your model, please? Also, it may also be useful to review your current lmeControls with the following command:
str(lmerControl()).

Comment: Also, what do you get if you fit the model to some subsets of subject IDs? Just use exactly the same design, except with fewer values for some factors to see if you can get a "singular fit". This [page](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** if in doubt try with a different optimizer and make sure your results are stable, but I would probably be willing to ignore this warning, especially because your data set is large (>10,000 obs).

`lme4` is reporting that some of the eigenvalues of the *estimated* Hessian (second derivative matrix) of the parameter estimates are large (>500); this suggests there might be numeric instability, which can sometimes be resolved (*if* you haven't done it already) by scaling & centering the parameters.

However, I'm guessing that this is due to a bad estimation of the Hessian, which leads to a misleading estimate of the eigenvalues.  This is a bit of a dirty secret of `lme4` - ever since we introduced convergence tests a few releases ago, we've been trying to get them right (which is hard).  In particular, we use a naive finite-difference approximation of the Hessian which works poorly for large (>10,000 obs) data sets ... here's an example from a simulation study (results in full [here](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/lme4_convergence)) - blue points are minimum eigenvalues of the Hessian estimated via Richardson extrapolation (`numDeriv::hessian`), pink points are min eigenvalues using our naive finite-difference rules.  Panels are with different optimizers; top row is unconstrained, bottom row is clamped to the range (0.5,5) ...

[image]